# Retrieve url query string using javascript to resolve a if/else statement and redirect

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement

I've read about 6 other posts on here about this topic and I still can’t seem to get this to work.

I want to use pure javascript to read a user defined url query string, then have it make a decision about where to redirect the user based on the information in the string.

I have the javascript saved in “script.js”,
this is part of a webpage “https://www.website.com/script.js”,
the url with the query string would look like this “https://www.website.com/script.js?bird=chicken”.

This is what my code looks like:

```
}
var birdtype = getQueryString('bird');
    if ( birdtype == [ chicken ])
        window.location.replace = "https://www.website.com/chicken.html";
    else
        window.location.replace = "https://www.website.com/turkey.html";
};
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .href property instead of replace like 
 `window.location.href = "https://www.website.com/chicken.html"`
to redirect to a different page.

Comment: I tried the href just to see if it fixed anything, but no luck. I don't believe the type of redirect is the problem. The problem is likely something with how the code is reading the string or some improper syntax. I don't use JS it could probably be some amateur mistake.

Comment: The code simply doesn't work, it just displays as text on the website. So i'm guessing it's either not retrieving the string or there's some sort of error I've made typing the code.